# Key word search just in one column of the file and keeping 2 words before and after key word

Tags: python, regex

Love Python and I am new to Python as well. Here with the help of community (users like Antti Haapala) I was able to proceed some extent. But I got stuck at the end. Please help. I have two tasks remaining before I get into my big data POC. (planning to use this code in 1+ million records in text file)

•   Search a key word in Column (C#3) and keep 2 words front and back to that key word.

•   Divert the print output to file.

•   Here I don’t want to touch C#1, C#2 for referential integrity purposes.

Really appreciate for all your help.

My input file:

```
C #1 C # 2  C# 3   (these are headings of columns, I used just for clarity)
12088|CITA|{Hello very nice lists, better to keep those
12089|CITA|This is great theme for lists keep it
```

Desired output file: (only change in Column 3 or last column)

```
12088|CITA|very nice lists, better to 
12089|CITA|theme for lists keep it
```

Code I am currently using:

```
s = """12088|CITA|{Hello very nice lists, better to keep those
12089|CITA|This is great theme for lists keep it """
for line in s.splitlines():  
    if not line.strip():
        continue  
    fields = line.split(None, 2)  
    joined = '|'.join(fields)
    print(joined)
```

BTW, If I use the key word search, I am looking my 1st and 2nd columns. My challenge is keep 1st and 2nd columns without change. And search only 3rd column and keep 2 words after/before key word/s.

Comment: Why do you not split on `'|'`, if this is your column separator?

Comment: What is the key word? It's "list", right? why don't you use that in your code?

Comment: I have to split because I have to separate 3 columns and to search only in 3rd columns. I don’t want to search in 1st or 2nd column. I want to search in only 3rd column. (Plus keep 2 key words before and after that search word in 3rd column). Is that make sense?

Comment: @Jan I am using the code to search keyword. But I am loosing my 1st and 2nd columns.. (nice is key word)             s = """ABC000012088 MONA    Nice guy, would like to talk to him - he is not so nice in my view


ABCRERERWEADF8702000012088  BONA    VERY rude but looks nice, time is 15:40

12088   CITA    {Hello very nice but very hard to convence"""

#str = s.read()

print (s.replace("  ", "|"))

findword = 'nice'
numwords = 2

for i in s.split('\n'):
    z = i.split(' ')

    for x in [x for (x, y) in enumerate(z) if findword in y]:
        print(' '.join(z[max(x-numwords,0):x+numwords+1]))

Comment: In your question you seemingly used `|` as the column separator, in the above comment you seemingly used a `  ` space as the column separator. Could you please agree with yourself what we have to understand? Is the separator different for different runs? what else?

Comment: What do you want to do for lines that do not contain the keyword? do you want to print them unmodified? do you want to skip them altogether? what else?

Comment: What do you want to do if there are multiple occurrences of the keyword in the 3rd column?

Comment: I am using | as a separator. If no match found, I would like to skip that line.Or I don't need to print. is that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

First I need to warn you that using this code for 1million records is dangerous. You are dealing with regular expression and this method is good as long as expressions are regular. Else you might end up creating, tons of cases to extract the data you want without extracting the data you don't want to.

For 1 million cases you'll need pandas as for loop is too slow.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.DataFrame({'C1': [12088
,12089],'C2':["CITA","CITA"],"C3":["Hello very nice lists, better to keep those",
                                   "This is great theme for lists keep it"]})
df["C3"] = df["C3"].map(lambda x:
                        re.findall('(?<=Hello)[\w\s,]*(?=keep)|(?<=great)[\w\s,]*',
                                   str(x)))
df["C3"]= df["C3"].map(lambda x: x[0].strip())
df["C3"].map(lambda x: x.strip())
```

which gives

```
df
      C1    C2                           C3
0  12088  CITA  very nice lists, better  to
1  12089  CITA      theme for lists keep it
```

Answer (score 0):

There are still some questions left about *how exactly* you strive to perform your keyword search. One obstacle is already contained in your example: how to deal with characters such as commas? Also, it is not clear what to do with lines that do not contain the keyword. Also, what to do if there are not two words before or two words after the keyword? I guess that you yourself are a little unsure about the exact requirements and did not think about all edge cases.

Nevertheless, I have made some "blind decisions" about these questions, and here is a naive example implementation that assumes that your keyword matching rules are rather simple. I have created the function `findword()`, and you can adjust it to whatever you like. So, maybe this example helps you finding your own requirements.

```
KEYWORD = "lists"

S = """12088|CITA|{Hello very nice lists, better to keep those
12089|CITA|This is great theme for lists keep it """


def findword(words, keyword):
    """Return index of first occurrence of `keyword` in sequence
    `words`, otherwise return None.

    The current implementation searches for "keyword" as well as
    for "keyword," (with trailing comma).
    """
    for test in (keyword, "%s," % keyword):
        try:
            return words.index(test)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return None


for line in S.splitlines():
    tokens = line.split("|")
    words = tokens[2].split()
    idx = findword(words, KEYWORD)
    if idx is None:
        # Keyword not found. Print line without change.
        print line
        continue
    l = len(words)
    start = idx-2 if idx > 1 else 0
    end = idx+3 if idx < l-2 else -1
    tokens[2] = " ".join(words[start:end])
    print '|'.join(tokens)
```

Test:

```
$ python test.py
12088|CITA|very nice lists, better to
12089|CITA|theme for lists keep it
```

PS: I hope I got the indices right for slicing. You should check, nevertheless.

Comment: Worked well. Is it possible to add additional keywords? And also if 3rd column has any Special characters like these “{“,“\”, “…”  etc. program is completely skipping the 1st and 2nd column. In fact I don’t need those characters. Is there a way I can clean the file 3rd column before I execute the program?

Comment: I am also getting "IndexError: list index out of range" error. Please help